# Rotate object around world origin

Tags: matrix, vector, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am currently trying to rotate a positionVector (0,0,1) around the world's x-axis and then rotate it back to its original position (just trying to get it to work). I read into rotation matrixes and got it working (sorta) but i am pretty stuck now.

As the image and code shows i create a cube at the starting point (0,0,1) and rotate it down in this case 30 degrees. But it seems to rotate more than 30 degrees when rotating clockwise. However when i rotate it back counterclockwise (30 degrees) it does rotate the proper amount. Which results in it not ending up at its starting point as it should (0,0,1).

[image]

---

I was wondering if any of you could shed some light on why this is happening and how to fix it. Thank you guys in advance!

```js
public float RotAngle = 330f;

public GameObject cube;
public GameObject original;
public GameObject relocator;
public GameObject initialTurn;

void Start ()
  {
        Vector3 pixelPos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
  
        original = GameObject.Instantiate(cube,pixelPos,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        original.name = "Original";


        initialTurn = GameObject.Instantiate(cube, pixelPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        initialTurn.name = "InitialTurn";

        relocator = GameObject.Instantiate(cube, pixelPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        relocator.name = "Relocator";
  }
void Update()
  {
        initialTurn.transform.position = RotateAroundOrigin(original.transform.position, RotAngle*Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        relocator.transform.position = RotateAroundOrigin(initialTurn.transform.position, (RotAngle * -1f) * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
  }

Vector3 RotateAroundOrigin(Vector3 startPos,float angle)
    {
        startPos.Normalize();
        startPos.y = (startPos.y * Mathf.Cos(angle)) - (startPos.z * Mathf.Sin(angle));
        startPos.z = (startPos.y * Mathf.Sin(angle)) + (startPos.z * Mathf.Cos(angle));
        return startPos.normalized;
    }
```

Comment: "But if i measure it by hand"  Like by putting a protractor on your monitor?  I'd be suspect of any hand measurements.  If for some reason you need to roll your own code, why not compare it to Unity's built in function: `transform.RotateAround (Vector3.zero, Vector3.forward, RotAngle*Mathf.Deg2Rad);`  You also shouldn't normalize 3D positions for rotation, normalization is usually only useful for directional vectors.

Comment: @Jerdak I assume "by hand" means he's checking the values in the inspector and not actually measuring it

Comment: @DavidReeve Nothing in the provided code or screenshot suggests a method for measurement. None of the public variables are a *calculated* rotational angle.  If that code exists it should be included as well as the actual calculated angle instead of a qualitative measurement like "seems to rotate slightly", but I suspect the OP has only eyeballed the angle.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, i guess i should have formulated that better. As @DavidReeve suggested i used the values in the inspector. I can't use transforms because the application i'm using this code for requires the use of vectors, but i will look into that. I can't actually work on the code right now but will do so in the morning and give a more in-depth explanation of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Here, I gave you 5 rep. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a direction vector pretty easily with a Quaternion.

Try this:

```
Vector3 RotateAroundOrigin(Vector3 startPos,float angle)
{
    startPos.Normalize();
    Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate [angle] degrees about the x axis.
    startPos = rot * startPos;
    return startPos;
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no need for `startPos.Normalize();`.